# Find String in between strings in CSV file. Return results and Rows

Tags: python, string, csv, rows

I have a CSV file I am trying to run through all rows and pull out a string between two strings using Python. I am new to python. I would then like to return the String found in a new column along with all other columns and rows. SAMPLE of How the CSV looks. I am trying to get everything between `/**ZTAG` & `ZTAG**\`

```
 Number Assignment_Group Notes
 123456 Team One    "2019-06-10 16:24:36 -  (Work notes)
 05924267            /**ZTAG-DEVICE-HW-APPLICATION-WONT-LAUNCH-STUFF- 
 SENT-REPAIR-FORCE-REPROCESSED-APPLICATION-ZTAG**\
 2019-05-24 16:44:48 - (Work notes)
 Attachment:snippet.PNG sys_attachment 
 sys_id:b08bf432db69ff083bfe3a10ad961961
```

I have been reading about this for a two days. I know I am missing 
   something 
   easy. I have looked at splitting the file in multiple ways.

import csv
   import pandas
   import re

```
f = open('test.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

#match = re.search("/**\ZTAG (.+?) ZTAG**\\", csv_f,flags=re.IGNORECASE)

for row in csv_f:
#print(re.split('/**ZTAG| ',csv_f))
#x = csv_f.split('/**ZTAG')
match = re.search("/**\ZTAG (.+?) ZTAG**\\", csv_f,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print (row[0])

f.close()

I would need to have all columns and rows return with new column 
containing string. EXAMPLE Below

Number, Assignment_group, Notes, TAG
123456, Team One,         All stuff, ZTAG-DEVICE-HW-APPLICATION-WONT- 
LAUNCH-STUFF-SENT-REPAIR-FORCE-REPROCESSED-APPLICATION-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this regular expression should work:

```
result = re.search("\/\**ZTAG(.*)ZTAG\**", text)
extracted_text = result.group(1)
```

this will give you the string

```
-DEVICE-HW-APPLICATION-WONT-LAUNCH-STUFF- SENT-REPAIR-FORCE-REPROCESSED-APPLICATION-
```

you can do this for each row in your for loop if necessary